# How well does Ubuntu run on the ASUS Eee tablet?

Tags: 12.04, asus, tablet, ubuntu-touch

I'm considering buying an ASUS Eee Transformer Prime. I mainly want it so I can do some light web coding on the go. I commute a lot and most of my time is spent on the trains unfortunately. I know that it is possible to install Ubuntu on the transformer prime.

I'm also aware that it is not stable since its something new. I'm wondering if anyone has tried it, how responsive/ fast is it? Does the batter die quickly?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu can be installed on the Transformer Prime. However, this is not a native installation as it runs on top of Android via VNC. Due to the limitations in VNC (and ultimately the hardware of the TFP), the graphics are pretty choppy. It is more of a proof of concept than it is a usable system.

Due to everything mentioned above, I ended up not buying a Transformer Prime. I had the same intentions as you and everything that I could find wasn't quite up to par. However, perhaps there are better/faster options than the VNC app.

Comment: hmm i wonder if its possible to run ubuntu 2d on it, that might make it run faster, I also found this about instaling native ubuntu on android http://eeepadhacks.net/transformer-hacks/how-to-install-native-ubuntu-on-eeepad-transformer/ if any one is willing to try it let me know how it works haha ;)

Comment: According to "http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1603921", there is a beta version from a user named lilstevie that might get you up and running (if beta testing has started yet). On page 19, he provides the link to "http://www.tegraflash.com/register" to register for the beta. I am in no part affiliated with that user or the link, so use your best judgement in applying and utilizing that hack. Hope this puts you on the right course. However, as of now, I think that VNC is the most stable route, which is why I chose that as my answer, versus concepts currently in testing.